# Fixed sized usable page with Template 10 with Hamburger?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, template10

I'm trying to create a drawing surface within a Template 10 UWP Hamburger template app with a template image in the background. Is there any way to force the main visual space to be non-scrollable? When I use the following XAML, the image expands off the screen as I stretch the app window wider.

```
        <!--  content  -->
    <StackPanel EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo.IsTargetElement="True"
                  Padding="12,8,0,0"
                  RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                  RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                  RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                  RelativePanel.Below="pageHeader">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ComboBox Name="TemplateComboBox" ItemsSource="{x:Bind _templates}" SelectionChanged="TemplateComboBox_SelectionChanged" PlaceholderText="Select a template...">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding}" />
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBlock x:Name="stateTextBox"
                   Margin="16,0,0,0"
                   Text="Current Visual State" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Name="DrawingGrid" Margin="0,5,5,5" >
            <Image Name="TemplateImage" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Uniform" />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

There is code in the code-behind to set the Image source as the combo selection changes. I just want the image to stretch to the current viewable area.

*sigh* Haven't even started with the Ink yet :(

Comment: How does setting Image Stretch="UniformToFill" work in your situation ?

Comment: It didn't actually change the output at all. The Image control stretches to allow it to "show" the whole bitmap, retaining aspect. I say "show" as most of it is off the viewport and so can't be seen.

I added some extra debug information and in fullscreen on my laptop, the page (including titlebar, etc.) has an ActualHeight of 897 whereas the Image control has an ActualHeight of 2802. It'll only really show about 870 of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could think about detecting the visible area's width and height, then set the width and height as your image control's width and height.

```
<Grid EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo.IsTargetElement="True"
              Padding="12,8,0,0"
              RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
              RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
              RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
              RelativePanel.Below="pageHeader">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="9*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ComboBox Name="TemplateComboBox" PlaceholderText="Select a template...">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding}" />
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBlock x:Name="stateTextBox"
               Margin="16,0,0,0"
               Text="Current Visual State" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Margin="0,5,5,5" x:Name="grid" Grid.Row="1">
            <ScrollViewer Name="scrollviewer" Width="{Binding ElementName=grid,Path=Width}" Height="{Binding ElementName=grid,Path=Height}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                <Image Name="TemplateImage" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="/Assets/pic.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Uniform" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
</Grid>
```

```
private void Page_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TemplateImage.Width = scrollviewer.ViewportWidth;
    TemplateImage.Height = scrollviewer.ViewportHeight;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really help at all. The idea is to have the image displayed in full and retaining its aspect ratio within the viewport of the screen, regardless of the size of the app window (or device that it is running on). In another sample app I'm able to make this work but it does not use Template10. I've even got the InkCanvas aligning with the visible component of the Image and scaling as the Image resizes.

I simply can't work out how to make the image stay within the visible bounds of the display window.

Comment: @RobSpencer It's ok. You could think about getting the visible area and set width and height for your image control. The ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth returns viewbale content's width. Please note that you should use Grid as the root panel, and use "*" to specify its row height. Because if you use stackPanel as root panel, the child Grid's default height will be 0, then you will not be able to see image control.

Comment: Thanks Xavier - that's what I was missing. I thought a StackPanel that was stretched by the RelativePanel associated properties would have been ok but apparently not. What I've done now is let the Image stretch with the Grid but resize the InkCanvas to match it.

Comment: Further to that reply, that approach has the advantage that if I implement some form of zoom feature for the image, the InkCanvas will remain intact.